# Delete Post from Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Post Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh0F3.png)
[retrieving the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDvc7.png)

I'm trying to delete posts from the Firebase Database. I'm having a ruff time removing values that are generated from an AutoID.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{
        let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
        let uid = user?.uid
        ref?.child("tests").child(uid!)/* The Posts AutoID*/.removeValue()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to retrieve the post IDs when the data is being fetched. For example, when fetching data just grab the post ID as well.

```
ref.child("tests").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
     for child in snapshot.children {
         let childSnap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
         print(childSnap.key) // SAVE THIS KEY SOMEWHERE, USE IT TO DELETE
     }
)}
```

Comment: I succesfully could take this save the key but where do I have to put it in an array or how and how do I would need to implement this in a tableview so that the tableview deletes the on ekey which I marked?

Comment: An array is fine, but ultimately you need to be able to associate a tableViewCell with the key. It depends how the table is being populated. Do you have a Struct that has TDatum, TFach, and TText? If so you should add another variable named "key" that holds the value of the autoID. I'd have to see how your data is structured to answer that question.

Comment: I updated the pictures above displaying the Post Structure and how i retrieve the data